# Sending large amounts of emails using PHP Mailer with CodeIgniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, phpmailer

I need help sending large amounts of emails through my newly designed automated email platform.

1. I am using PHP Mailer Library to send emails to my contacts
2. I built my script in CodeIgniter 3
3. I am using VPS level 3 from Godaddy
4. My email system freezes after 5 or more emails in mail queue manager
5. I am assuming that my script is designed for large volumes of emails.
6. Mail queue manager in Godaddy WHM panel shows all my emails as FROZEN

---

***Part of my script:***

```
$options = [
    'user_id' => $this->me->id,
    'limit' => 200000,
    'type' => $exploded[1]
];
    $this->data['contacts'] = $this->crm_model->get_portal_contacts($options);
    $emails = array();
    foreach ($this->data['contacts'] as $contact) {
         $this->data['fullname'] = get_user($contact)->full_name(false);
         $emaildata = [
          'from' => ['name' => 'Domain', 'email' => '<no-reply@domai.org>\r\n'],
          'to' => strip_tags(get_user($contact)->email),
          'subject' => $this->data['email']['email_subject'],
          'message' => $this->load->view('np_sh/email/email-template', $this->data, TRUE)
         ];
         $status = _send_mail($emaildata);
    }
```

---

`_send_mail()` function is merging `$emaildata` variable with the default parameters and preparing to send email using PHPMailer and returning `boolean` status.

Comment: are you sure go-daddy doesn't have an email limit? -- and i have always considered them one of the worst hosts.

Comment: if you want to have a good change of email arriving you need to consider reverse dns records, domain keys, SPF records etc spammers have made it a fun game

Comment: @nogad I am not sure...

Comment: how about asking them then?